# can't delete items from cart on Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to delete all the added to cart items by pressing button clear.
I started to write a function but it refused to work.
I consider the mistake is that I didn't push items to cart.
How can I do these 2 things ? Anyway, if you see any mistakes, please, mention.

```
angular.module('TransactionApp', [])
    .controller('TransactionsCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.title = 'Add to cart';

        $scope.itemsArray = [{
                price: 50,
                name: "Whey protein",
                img: 'img/item-1.png',
                quantity: 0
            },
            {
                price: 60,
                name: "Protein bar",
                img: 'img/item-1.png',
                quantity: 0
            },
            {
                price: 35,
                name: "BCAA",
                img: 'img/item-1.png',
                quantity: 0
            },
            {
                price: 50,
                name: "Whey protein",
                img: 'img/item-1.png',
                quantity: 0
            },
            {
                price: 60,
                name: "Protein bar",
                img: 'img/item-1.png',
                quantity: 0
            },
            {
                price: 80,
                name: "BCAA",
                img: 'img/item-1.png',
                quantity: 0
            }

        ];

        $scope.addTo = function(item) {
            item.quantity += 1;
        }

        $scope.getCost = function(item) {
            return item.quantity * item.price;

        }

        $scope.cart = [];

        $scope.getTotal = function() {
            return $scope.itemsArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b.price * b.quantity, 0);
        }

        $scope.clearCart = function() {
            return $scope.cart.length = 0;
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Juse reset the items in the array,

```
   $scope.cart = [];
```

you do not need to return anything, and you can get the count by using length.

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
$scope.clearCart = function() {
  $scope.cart = [];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it empty use following:

```
$scope.cart = [];
```

or to reduce one by one:

```
$scope.cart.slice(start, end);//start is an index from where you want to delete and the end is number which represents how many to delete.
```

To insert something on the array at last index, you do require to push:

```
$scope.cart.push(item);
```